# unexpected output from C++ multiset lower_bound

Tags: c++, stl, multiset

Wondeirng why below code returns `1`? I never insert `1` into the `multiset` container.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main ()
{
  std::multiset<int> mymultiset;
  std::multiset<int>::iterator itlow;

  mymultiset.insert(-3);
  itlow = mymultiset.lower_bound (3);
  std::cout << *itlow << endl; // output 1

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: check for end() - lower_bound Return value: Iterator pointing to the first element that is not less than value, or last if no such element is found.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky, understand check for end, but why 1 is returned? Where it is coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mymultiset.lower_bound(3)` returns the lowest location in the container where `3` could go, and that's at the end of the container. So `itlow` is equal to `mymultiset.end()`, and it is not dereferenceable. `std::cout << *itlow` has undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks Pete, I think 1 is returned as it is undefined behavior. Mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get an Iterator which his lower bound is 3, and your maximum value is -3. So you've got an end iterator, which his value is undefined.
You should use `multiset::begin()` as your Iterator, or put something like `itlow = mymultiset.lower_bound (-4);` which is not very gentle.

Answer (score 0):

Hi to clarify my understanding
I have one multiset which contains 1 and 5.

```
mset.insert(1);
mset.insert(5);
auto it = s.lower_bound(6);
cout<<*it<<endl;
```

Now, from the above answer, I will be getting 2 since that is the location where the value 6 can fit inside the container. Am I right?

Next, if I search for the value 4, I am getting 5.
Here I don't think the iterator has reached the mset.end(). 
Am I right?

Thanks